# How to update Adwords Shopping Campaign

Tags: google, google-ads

I have a question on Adwords Shopping Campaign but can't find the answer anywhere.

1. I generated a Google shopping feed and submitted it to Google Merchant Center.
2. I linked Google Merchant Center with my AdWords account
3. I created a Shopping Campaign on basis of the shopping feed.

However, I updated some products and info in the shopping feed, these updates are visible in the Merchant account but not in AdWords. How can I synchronize these accounts so that my Google Shopping Adwords campaign will be updated according to updates in the Google feed? Or should I create a new campaign every time?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you should wait some hours. How is it going now?